# Connection pooling not used from websphere

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, connection-pooling, websphere-liberty

I am trying to deploy my worklight project's `war`  in websphere liberty profile 8.5.5.1 . However, I get this exception when I deploy my project . I researched little bit and came to know that my application is trying to use Apache connection pooling instead of Websphere . And this feature is not supported in websphere .  I was wondering if any one can give me some idea to use websphere datasrouces instead of Apache connection pooling.
Below is the relevant stacktrace :

```
   Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][10389][12245][3.67.27] Failure in loading native library db2jcct2, java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no db2jcct2 in java.library.path:  ERRORCODE=-4472, SQLSTATE=null
            at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:733)
            at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:66)
            at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:102)
            at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t2.a.a(a.java:37)
            at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t2.T2Configuration.<clinit>(T2Configuration.java:95)
            at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:435)
            at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:115)
            at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
            at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
            at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
            at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
```

Comment: Did you already review this module? http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/11_01_Moving_from_development_environment_to_stand-alone_QA_and_production_servers.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I had some issue on deploying worklight runtime. I had all the database configuration correct, however was facing this issue. I just redeployed worklight-runtime from server configuration tool and this problem is fixed.